# Query to retrieve main records in one table and its all sub records from another table

Tags: mysql

Let us suppose we have tables like questions and answers

### **Questions table**

```
qno question
1   first question
2   second question
```

### **Answers table**

```
ano qno answer
1   1   first answer for q1
2   1   second answer for q1
3   2   first answer for q2
4   1   third answer for q1
5   2   second answer for q2
```

Now I need a single query in mysql that can output each question and all of its answers

### **Expected output**

```
qno ano    question                      answer
--- ---    ----------                   -------------------
1    0   first question                   
1    1                                  first answer for q1
1    2                                  second answer for q1
1    4                                  third answer for q1
2    0   second question                
2    3                                  first answer for q2
2    5                                  second answer for q2
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

Normally a `JOIN` doesn't output results in the format you show as your desired result. The `JOIN` operator in SQL matches rows from one table to rows from the other, so it will produce the `question` repeatedly, which is not what you want.

To get what you want, use `UNION` instead of `JOIN`, and position them into columns like you want:

```
(SELECT qno, 0, question, NULL AS `answer` FROM questions)
UNION
(SELECT qno, ano, NULL, answer FROM answers)
ORDER BY qno, ano
```

For what it's worth, I agree with the comments from Strawberry. I wouldn't actually do this in my application. I would fetch the data in a simpler format, and in my application code present the data in the layout desired.

My example above is only to show that manipulating the data into that layout in SQL makes the code less clear.

Comment: @Praveen Don't do this. :-(